# Adding and remove items from a string without using arrays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add and remove things in a string with using arrays.  However this following script I created is not working as it doesn't remove numbers that have been submitted:

```
function updateCCList(id)
{
     var MemberClicked = '[' + id + ']';
     var ListClickedMembers = document.frmSendMail.hidSenderList.value;
     if(ListClickedMembers.indexOf(MemberClicked) == -1)
     {
          ListClickedMembers += MemberClicked;
     }
     else
     {
          ListClickedMembers = ListClickedMembers.replace(/' + MemberClicked + '/g,'');
     }
     alert(ListClickedMembers);
     document.frmSendMail.hidSenderList.value += ListClickedMembers;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem:

```
ListClickedMembers = ListClickedMembers.replace(/' + MemberClicked + '/g,'');
```

The first RegExp there looks bad.  I think you mean `new RegExp('\\['+id+'\\]')`

In case you care about avoiding duplicate entries:

```
document.frmSendMail.hidSenderList.value += ListClickedMembers;
```

You don't need `+=` there, `=` will suffice.